# How to store settings credentials in Java

Tags: java

I have a XML file which is used to store the settings of application. When I open the application the XML file is parsed with JAX-B and the credentials are stored into the memory. Now I have to choose which Java collection I have to choose. I prefer to use Java Object which holds many small Java Objects. But there still other options like hashmap. Which Java Collection will consume minimum amount of memory and will be appropriate for this task?

Comment: Have thought about [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a collection here. Just keep the JAX-B POJO around since it has the credentials. Moving the credentials would be a waste of resources in this case.

Comment: Yes but keeping JAX-B always initialized maybe will take more resources?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) library for this task. It also allows for reading XML configuration files and you can easily access and change the various properties. Saving and loading of configuration files is also included.